# datatable does not support if more than 60000 records are being fetched

Tags: php, json, loops, datatable, shopify

we want to store large number of data (more than 60K rows ) in datatable but the datatable fails to executes and output is not coming well. The datatable will not fails till 20000 records. Here is fhe following source code

```
 <div class="row">
                        <table id="customer_table"  class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                         <thead>    
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Group</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


    <?php   for($p=1;$p<=200;$p++)

    {

    $ch = curl_init("https://$shop_name/admin/customers.json?limit=250&page=".$p."");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json",
                                        "X-Shopify-Access-Token: $store_token"));
                     $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    $decoded_customer = json_decode($result, true); 
                    //var_dump($decoded_customer); 
                    ?>

    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($decoded_customer['customers']);$i++)

    {
    ?>
            <tr>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $decoded_customer['customers'][$i]['id']; ?>" >
            <td>#</td>
            <td><?php echo $decoded_customer['customers'][$i]['first_name']." ".$decoded_customer['customers'][$i]['last_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $decoded_customer['customers'][$i]['email']; ?></td>
            <td>

      <select class="form-control" >
           <option value="" >
               No Selected
            </option>
                <?php 
                session_start();

                $shop_name = $_SESSION['shop'];
                include("dbconnect.php");

                $sql_select_tbl_shop = "SELECT * FROM `store_info_tbl` WHERE `store_name` = '$shop_name'";
                $select_tbl_shop = mysql_query($sql_select_tbl_shop);

                if(mysql_num_rows($select_tbl_shop)>0){

                $row_select_val=mysql_fetch_array($select_tbl_shop );
                $shop_id=$row_select_val['id']; 

                //select selected group name
                $customer_id=$decoded_customer['customers'][$i]['id'];


                $sqlselectgroup_customer="SELECT * FROM `tbl_group` WHERE `store_name`='$shop_id'";
                $resselectgroup_customer=mysql_query($sqlselectgroup_customer);
                if(mysql_num_rows($resselectgroup_customer))
                {
                  while($rowselectgroup_customer=mysql_fetch_assoc($resselectgroup_customer))
                  { 
                $sqlselectcustomergroup="SELECT * FROM `tbl_customer_detail` WHERE `customer_shop_id`='$customer_id'";
                $resselectcustomergroup=mysql_query($sqlselectcustomergroup);

                if(mysql_num_rows($resselectcustomergroup)>0){
                //$rowselectcustomer=mysql_num_rows($resselectcustomergroup);

                 //$rowid=mysql_fetch_array('group_name');
                 $rowid=mysql_fetch_array($resselectcustomergroup);
                 $customer_group=$rowid['group_name'];

                ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $rowselectgroup_customer['id']; ?>" <?php if($customer_group==$rowselectgroup_customer['id']) { ?>selected <?php } ?> >
            <?php echo $rowselectgroup_customer['group_name']; ?>
            </option>
              <?php } else{ ?>

           <option value="<?php echo $rowselectgroup_customer['id']; ?>" >
            <?php echo $rowselectgroup_customer['group_name']; ?>
            </option>

                <?php  } } } } ?>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } } ?>



    </tbody>

    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" > 
               $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('#customer_table').DataTable();

               }); 
               $(document).on('click','.save',function(){
                   var shopify_customer_id=$(this).parent().parent().find('input').val();
                   var customer_name=$(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq(1).html();
                   var customer_email=$(this).parent().parent().find('td').eq(2).html();
                   var group_name=$(this).parent().parent().find('td').find('select').val();
                  //alert(shopify_customer_id+customer_name+customer_email+group_name);


                  $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "ajaxcustomerdata.php",
                        data: {
                            shopify_customer_id:shopify_customer_id,
                            customer_name:customer_name,
                            customer_email:customer_email,
                            group_name:group_name
                        },
                        success: function (data){
                           alert(data);

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        }
                    });



                   });

            </script>
            <script>

            </script>



    </div>
```

If any one has any kind of suggestion please help me out to resolve this problem

Comment: Since this is a DB question, you might want to add what database you're using? Also, you might want to let us know why you would ever need to fetch 60k rows in one go?

Comment: wow! 200 curl requests, each fetching 250 results and then using `session_start()` and including `dbconnect.php` in every iteration....

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: actually the limit of fetching customers is only 250 per page ie why we have to loop the customers

Comment: We are using php version 5.5.38 on our server

Answer (score 1):

Please read https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html official post from data table. it is showing how to add thousands of record added in data table.

Below is example of this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        serverSide: true,
        ordering: false,
        searching: false,
        ajax: function ( data, callback, settings ) {
            var out = [];

            for ( var i=data.start, ien=data.start+data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                out.push( [ i+'-1', i+'-2', i+'-3', i+'-4', i+'-5' ] );
            }

            setTimeout( function () {
                callback( {
                    draw: data.draw,
                    data: out,
                    recordsTotal: 160421,
                    recordsFiltered: 160421
                } );
            }, 50 );
        },
        scrollY: 600,
        scroller: {
            loadingIndicator: true
        }
    } );
} );
```

html for datatable :

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>ZIP / Post code</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: we use this but its also not working same problem when we use   https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

Comment: can you tell me what is an error or anything so i can better understand

Comment: what about the data which is coming from the database

Answer (score 0):

Though you should not load so many records at once, it will make your server insecure and you may go out of resources if so many multiple request are made at once. You should try Ajax based Datatable.

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Link above uses the AJAX call to load data so that you don't have to query all 60,000 rows.

Comment: That's not an "ajax based database". It's just pagination, which happens to be using ajax to update a table. You should also explain in your answer what the proposed solution is since links can change an if it does, this answer will no longer make sense.